# Is there a Python equivalent to dereferencing in Perl?

Tags: python, perl, numpy, reference, runtime

I'm currently porting a code base, I initially implemented in Perl, to Python. The following short piece of code takes up about 90% of the significant runtime when I run on the whole dataset.

```
    def equate():
        for i in range(row):
            for j in range(row):
                 if adj_matrix[i][j] != adj_matrix[mapping[i]][mapping[j]]:
                 return False
        return True
```

Where equate is a closure inside of another method, row is an integer, adj_matrix is a list of lists representing a matrix and mapping is a list representing a vector.

The equivalent Perl code is as follows:

```
sub equate
{
    for ( 0..$row)
    {
        my ($smrow, $omrow) = ($$adj_matrix[$_], $$adj_matrix[$$mapping[$_]]); #DEREF LINE
        for (0..$row)
        {
            return 0 if $$smrow[$_] != $$omrow[$$mapping[$_]];
        }
    }
    return 1;
 }
```

This is encapsulated as a sub ref in the outer subroutine, so I don't have to pass variables to the subroutine.

In short, the Perl version is much much faster and my testing indicates that it is due to the dereferencing in "DEREF LINE". I have tried what I believed was the equivalent in Python:

```
    def equate():
        for i in range(row):
            row1 = adj_matrix[i]
            row2 = adj_matrix[mapping[i]]
            for j in range(row):
                 if row1[j] != row2[mapping[j]]:
                 return False
        return True
```

But this was an insignificant improvement. Additionally, I tried using a [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) matrix to represent adj_matrix, but again this was a small improvement probably because adj_matrix is typically a small matrix so the overhead from NumPy is much greater, and I'm not really doing any matrix math operations.

I welcome any suggestion to improve the runtime of the Python `equate` method and an explanation why my "improved" Python `equate` method is not much better. While I consider myself a competent Perl programmer, I am a Python novice.

---

ADDITIONAL DETAILS:

I am using Python 3.4, although similar behavior was observed when I initially implemented it in 2.7. I switched to 3.4 since the lab I work in uses 3.4.

As for the contents of the vectors, allow me to provide some background so the following details make sense. This is part of a algorithm to identify subgraph isomorphisms between two chemical compounds (a and b) represented by the graphs A and B respectively, where each atom is a node and each bond an edge. The above code is for the simplified case where A = B, so I am looking for symmetrical transformations of the compound (planes of symmetry), and the size of A in number of atoms is N. Each atom is assigned a unique index beginning at zero.

Mapping is a 1D vector of dimensions 1xN where each element in a mapping is an integer. `mapping[i] = j`, represents that atom with index i (will refer to as atom i or generically atom 'index') is currently mapped to atom j. The absence of a mapping is indicated by j = -1.

Adj_matrix is a 2D matrix of dimensions NxN where each element adj_matrix[i][j] = k is a natural number and represents the presence and order of an edge between atoms i and j in compound A. If k = 0, there is no such edge (AKA no bond between i and j) else k > 0 and k represents the order of the bond between atoms i and j.

When A != B, there are two different adj_matrices that are compared in `equate` and the size of a and b in atoms is Na and Nb. Na does not have to equal Nb, but Na =< Nb. I only mention this as optimizations are possible for the special case that are not valid in the general case, but any advice would be helpful.

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: Can you provide more details on the dimensions of your vectors and matrices and the contents of mapping?

Comment: It's possible that to get a meaningful speedup you'll need to refactor the code.  It depends on how often you create a new `adj_matrix`, how often you change `mapping`, etc.  If the matrix is small, you may be better off creating the "mapped" matrix in tandem with the original, and then just checking them for equality.

Comment: I have added additional details to the original post. If these are insufficient, I would be happy to provide more. 


Mapping is changed frequently, I permute all possible valid mappings and find the ones that satisfy the equate condition when row is equal to N. I determine all valid mappings by precomputing which values of mapping[i] = j are allowed by computing a mapping matrix, where m_matrix[i][j] = k and k = 1 when i and j are mappable (same element type usually) and values of mapping[i] = j must satisfy m_matrix[i][j] == 1. I check this condition before equate.

Comment: Your edit suggests your real question is more about how to efficiently compute graph isomorphisms.  You might have more luck asking a separate question where you explain your data and describe the problem you're trying to solve in conceptual terms, instead of jumping right into this implementation.  There is for instance a Python library [networkx](http://networkx.github.io/) which includes many graph-related functions, including isomorphism.  More generally, although it may not be fun, the way to make your code faster could be to rethink your data structures at a more basic level.

Comment: I am genuinely curious as to how to make that section of code perform better. The algorithm from which this is taken is part of my dissertation work and portions not shown here offer functionality that cannot be easily implemented into the pre-existing libraries for graph isomorphisms in the context of chemical structures. The original Perl algorithm is more efficient for our task than the libraries I tried, but this is no longer true in Python due to the increased runtime. While the current version is sufficiently fast, as a learning experience / curiosity I want to improve it if possible

Comment: Roughly what's the size of `row` - more like `10` or `1000`?  How sparse is `adj_matrix` (proportion of zeros)?  How much faster is a typical `False` case (which exits early) than a `True` (which iterates through the whole thing)?

Comment: The size of row can vary but is usually between 50 and 300. adj_matrix is typically very sparse; for any row or column there is usually a maximum of 4 non-zero entities. The majority of cases will produce False as isomorphisms are relatively rare and when row is large the time savings from detecting the false case is significant.

Comment: It may be worth looking at a sparse representation of `adj_matrix`.  `scipy.sparse` has several, or you could just use a Python dictionary.  I'd have to experiment a bit to see how the mapping would work.

Comment: I'll check out the dictionary implementation. I had played around with using a hash in Perl and found it to be more memory efficient but less fast than the array implementation; however, I have not tried the python equivalent. Nonetheless, a sparse matrix is probably better in many ways, at least memory-wise which is a plus as even the slower version is sufficiently fast for the current datasets. This is probably premature optimization but I so do enjoy minimize runtime, especially while I'm on break from official work.

Comment: Tip: `$a->[$i]` is preferred over `$$a[$i]` since it's far more readable.

Comment: I'm not sure I would say far more readable, especially when the accessor package is being used and '->' could be a normal perl deref or an accessor. I think for objects, such as they are in Perl, '->' makes more sense but for simple datastructures the 'standard' Perl way is equally ambiguous. However, I'm biased, Perl was the first language I truly learned and the languages without $$ @$ $! and such are weird to me.

Answer (score 4):

With numpy you could vectorize your whole code as follows, assuming `adj_matrix` and `mapping` are numpy arrays:

```
def equate():
    row1 = adj_matrix[:row]
    row2 = adj_matrix[mapping[:row]]
    return np.all(row1 == row2)
```

It doesn't break out early of the loop if it finds a mismatch, but unless your arrays are huge, the speed of NumPy is going to dominate.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tonight and see if it offers an improvement. Due to the highly variable size of the graphs, it could be the case that the improvement on the 10% that are very large makes up for the overhead on the smaller 90% of cases.

Comment: In my testing `adj_matrix==adj_matrix[np.ix_(mapping, mapping)]` produced the correct match with OP iterative solution.

Comment: Thanks, that is a significant improvement over the original. In my first testing of this it did give some different answers than the original equate method, but I am not checking the output very smartly so it could be that the results are in a different order or I am doing something silly. Nonetheless it is a step in the right direction. +1 and once I confirm that it is equivalent (it should be if you and I are both understanding numpy stuff correctly) it will be the accepted answer.

Comment: hpaulj: The code you provided will not run for me, I get "truth value of an array is ambiguous", I assume that I would need to use np.ix on both sides as follows:

`all(adj_matrix[ix_(values,values)] == adj_matrix[ix_(mapping,mapping)])`

but returning this does not give the same results for me, but I think this is equivalent to my original, right? 

Sorry for the noob questions and comments, python is still strange to me.

Comment: So I got your method working hpaulj, had to add mapping[:row] instead of mapping since there are '-1' placeholders is mapping for the not-yet mapped atoms (i'm searching depth-wise, so atom 9 is unmapped if row < 9) I should have explained that more clearly in my post. Thanks for the suggestion.